# CGAL : getting mesh from polyhedral envelope

Tags: mesh, cgal

The example here [example](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2polyhedral_envelope_8cpp-example.html)

construct an envelope and use it to check if a point is inside it.

Would it be possible to get the mesh from the envelope ?

Answer (score 0):

The mesh is not explicitly stored as internally only an AABB-tree of faces is constructed.

Comment: Is it possible to get the AABB-tree?

Comment: No but you are free to wrap the creation of the envelope class in your own struct that will store a reference to the input mesh.

Comment: The input mesh I do have. Maybe you mean the mesh from the envelpe? Can you please give an example ?

Comment: The envelope is basically building a set of internal triangles stored in an AABB-tree.